# Convert HTML to wellformed XML

Tags: java, html, xml, xhtml

I am searching for a way/library to convert HTML input to a wellformed XML in Java. At the moment i am using jTidy but the problem is that jTidy does a lot of cleaning that i don't want to have. For example sometimes jTidy removes whitespaces or tags.

So is there a way to get wellformed XML without the "intelligent" cleaning of jTidy?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/). This library has a lot of [settings](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/settings.html) which could be useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

There is the SAX-Parser, which can parse HTML. After that you can save it as XML.

Documentation: [parse-html($html as xs:string)](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/functions/saxon/parse-html.html)